# Permission denied createobject("outlook.application") asp classic

Tags: vba, outlook, asp-classic

I am trying to create the object outlook.application using the code below

```
test = createobject("outlook.application")
```

However when this is run I receive the following error

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Permission denied: 'createobject'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you do with Outlook?  Are you running against an Exchange mailbox?

Comment: It's to create a meeting request and yes, the server running the code has outlook 2013 installed and connected to an exchange account

Comment: I don't have a full blown answer for you, but try one or both of the following: 1) Configure the DCOM permissions (Start > Run > dcomcnfg) for Outlook, 2) Use a different IIS user, or give the current IIS user elevated permissions.

Comment: And..it is possible to use Outlook and any other Office app from IIS. It's certainly not recommended and it's a pain to get it working right but sometimes you have no choice.

Comment: There is a good reason why it is not recommended - it tends to blow up at the most inappropriate moment. Like when you deploy your solution in production. If you are fine with that, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Answer (score -2):

Outlook or any other Office app cannot be used in a service (such as IIS). In your particular case, [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) is a good alternative.